# How to make error go to catch statement

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase

When using the firebase node library, the real time database, a promise is returned, but what happens if an exception happens in my code in the `.then()` method? How could I make the code go to the `.catch()` method? Here is the code that I am trying to make go to the catch method.

```
admin.database().ref('/something/something').once('value').then(function(data: admin.database.DataSnapshot) {
    if(data.val() === null) {
        return new TypeError('invalid');
    }
}).catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);  
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simplify your error handling an make you code more readable using async-await

```
async function asyncFunction() {
    try {
        const data: admin.database.DataSnapshot = await admin.database().ref('/something/something').once('value');
        if(data.val() === null) {
            throw new TypeError('invalid');
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);  
    }
}
```

Comment: Seeing `var` and `async/await` (es8) in the same function makes me smile. Use `const/let` (es6)

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT Yes, yes you are right, changed it to `const` :). But for `async/await` you don't have to wait until es8 for async-await if you use typescript :)

Comment: Oh that's right didn't saw that was about typescript! Nice catch

Comment: Your answer helped me clarify how to use `async/await`. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help, I'm a big async await fan I want to see it used everywhere :)

Answer (score 2):

When you hear about `try` and `catch`, the third word you need to think about is `throw`!

```
throw new TypeError('invalid')
```

[image]